# $\int^{2\pi}_0\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}d\theta$

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to find:
$$\int\limits^{2\pi}_0\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}d\theta$$
while $\hat r$ is as usually used in Physics (i.e. for $\theta=0.5\pi$ you get $\hat r=\hat y$, and for $\theta=\pi$ you get $\hat r=-\hat x$).

If I understand correctly, because $\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}=\text{sin}\left(\pi-\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\text{sin}\left(\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}\right)$, it holds that the $\hat x$ components of $\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}$ are identical for $\theta=t,2\pi-t$, while the $\hat y$ components are equal but opposite.
Therefore:
$$\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}d\theta=\left(\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}d\theta\hat{x}\right)\hat{x}=\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\text{cos}\theta d\theta\hat{x}$$

Now we have:
$$\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\text{cos}\theta d\theta\hat{x}=\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\left(2\text{cos}^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}-1\right)d\theta\hat{x}$$
I managed to solve the last integral, and thus got:
$$\overset{2\pi}{\underset{0}{\int}}\text{sin}\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\hat{r}d\theta=-\frac{4}{3}\hat{x}$$

My question is:
Is my solution the simplest one, or have I missed some better way to solve the problem?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that is the definition of $\hat{\theta}$? In physics the vector you described is referred to as $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ is something different.

Comment: @OfekGillon I guess you are right, and edited accordingly. Please edit my question further if you think I got something wrong.